# Consultation about show location on map by street name

Tags: android

How i can show location on map by street name using android and java ?

For example: i'll type in my program street,city - and i get the location on map

i have this sample:

```
Intent i = new
        Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:31.06221,33.781642"));
        startActivity(i);
```

how to change this code for inserting street and city ? i try this:

something like: `Uri.parse("geo:empire state building"));`

but it dont work    ):

Comment: Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reverse-Geocoding with `Geocoder` class

Example for achieving coordinates of Empire State Building:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                "empire state building", 5);
            String add = "";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                String coords = "geo:" + String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLongitude());
                Intent i = new
                      Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                             Uri.parse(coords));
                startActivity(i);
            }  
    } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i try this, but it dont work for me. i update my question

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder is great and thanks llya.

this query should be executed in a separate thread, for example, AsyncTask, here is a sample code, hope to be helpful.

```
public class AsyncTaskToQueryLocation extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {

private WeakReference<Context> m_Context;
private WeakReference<UserLocationManager> m_Manager;
private WeakReference<OnGeoLocationQueryListener> m_Listener;
private Locale m_Locale;
private String m_ParsedLocation;

public AsyncTaskToQueryLocation(Context context,
        UserLocationManager manager, OnGeoLocationQueryListener listener,
        Locale locale) {

    m_Context = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    m_Manager = new WeakReference<UserLocationManager>(manager);
    m_Listener = new WeakReference<OnGeoLocationQueryListener>(listener);
    m_Locale = locale;
    m_ParsedLocation = null;
}

@Override
protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {

    Context context = m_Context.get();
    if (context == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if ((params == null) || (params.length == 0) || (params[0] == null)) {
        return null;
    }

    m_ParsedLocation = params[0];
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, m_Locale);
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                m_ParsedLocation, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            return new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude(), addresses
                    .get(0).getLongitude());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {

    OnGeoLocationQueryListener listener = m_Listener.get();
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onGeoLocationQueryFinished(m_ParsedLocation, latLng);
    }

    onCancelled();
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {

    UserLocationManager manager = m_Manager.get();
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.notifyAsyncTaskFinish(AsyncTaskToQueryLocation.class
                .getSimpleName());
    }

    clearReference();
}

private void clearReference() {

    // release the weak reference.
    m_Listener.clear();
    m_Manager.clear();
    m_Context.clear();
}
```

}