# Google Map Android search location

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm Trying to make Google Map search by address

here is my code for cari.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class cari extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity {

       TextView error,pt;
       EditText cm;
       String i,returnStringLancar,stat;
       Geocoder geoCoder;
       GeoPoint p;
       MapController controller;
       MapView map;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

       @Override


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search);

            pt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.peta);
            cm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cariMap);




       }

       public void clickHandler(View view){
           Intent a = null;
            switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.show:
                geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(cm.getText().toString(),5);
                if(addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                     p = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                                      (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                       controller.animateTo(p);
                       controller.setZoom(12);

                       MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                     List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
                     listOfOverlays.clear();
                     listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                       map.invalidate();
                       cm.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(cari.this);
                        adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                        adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                        adb.setPositiveButton("Close",null);
                        adb.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                break;
       }
       }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my MapOverlay.java

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    Context context;
    GeoPoint p;
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);         
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my layout xml:

search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android.autoText="true"
    />

<EditText 
android:text="Enter your address" 
android:id="@+id/address" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
<Button 
android:text="Search" 
android:id="@+id/launchmap" 
android:layout_width="150px" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is when I write name of one street in editText (example : 1152 1st Avenue) and press the search button, it will show the location (1152 1st Avenue) on a Google-map.

when i run this program,,,it says

" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{udin.googlemap2/udin.googlemap2.GoogleMap2}:"

and this

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: udin.googlemap2.GoogleMap2 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/udin.googlemap2-2.apk]"

can you help me?any help will i appreciate....Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace? Atleast a few more details from the Logcat, and additionally the xml file where your map element is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` is given in manifest..

Answer (score 0):

You could use Android's Geocoder for this purpose. It can return a list of Known address' from a given location name. You can then use the `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` on each of these address' to get one that's suitable for you.

The `getFromLocationName()` is useful in this regard. [Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for details.

Once you have the lat-long, you can use [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) to add an overlay item at that location on a map.

Comment: i have edit my question....maybe you can help....i really appreciate your help Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post: [Consultation about show location on map by street name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100028/consultation-about-show-location-on-map-by-street-name/13101238#13101238)

About `EditText` and `Button` you can read here: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html)

Comment: i have edit my question....maybe you can help....i really appreciate your help
Thanks anyway