# Search specific location in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have problem with search location in Google Map Android

here is my code for cari.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class cari extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity {

       TextView error,pt;
       EditText cm;
       String i,returnStringLancar,stat;
       Geocoder geoCoder;
       GeoPoint p;
       MapController controller;
       MapView map;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

       @Override


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search);

            pt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.peta);
            cm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cariMap);




       }

       public void clickHandler(View view){
           Intent a = null;
            switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.show:
                geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(cm.getText().toString(),5);
                if(addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                     p = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                                      (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                       controller.animateTo(p);
                       controller.setZoom(12);

                       MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                     List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
                     listOfOverlays.clear();
                     listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                       map.invalidate();
                       cm.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(cari.this);
                        adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                        adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                        adb.setPositiveButton("Close",null);
                        adb.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                break;
       }
       }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my MapOverlay.java

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    Context context;
    GeoPoint p;
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);         
        return true;
    }
}
```

the purpose of this program is for search location in Google Map by address (example: 5th Avenue).

but when I deploy this, it show error like this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{udin.googlemap2/udin.googlemap2.GoogleMap2}:

and this:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: udin.googlemap2.GoogleMap2 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/udin.googlemap2-1.apk]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13552344/1782481 Please do not repost your questions, just improve on the version from before. This is not going to get you any more help if you post the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` is given in android manifest..It will be alright.